# PHP and 2 Databases in mysql

Tags: mysqli, mysql-workbench

How can I connected 2 databases? On the first I validate the  users and if the user is authorized, then it will access to the main database. I do this for security.  Thanks for yours answer.

Comment: Why this solution is more secure than having only one database ? Do you expect first database is less secure than the second one? I think you don't need 2 databases...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create two connection to mysql use different variable for connection

```
<?php
$con1 = mysqli_connect("db1server","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$con2 = mysqli_connect("db2server","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

?>
```

and run query on the required server

Comment: I have a database that has a customer table with id but I need that when a user login first check if a client is in the bd. If it is, access the second database where you can just verify your password and other data required in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can Access any number of data bases

for eg.

```
$dbcon1= mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname1);


$dbcon2=mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname2);
```

Important thing to NOTE when you are using many database make sure you close(mysqli_close(dbconnection))the database,
  before accessing other  database  as a good practice

Answer (score 0):

You should check the function [mysqli::select_db/mysqli_select_db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php).

Here is an example:

**Object oriented style**

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

/* change db to world db */
$mysqli->select_db("world");

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = $result->fetch_row();
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    $result->close();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

**Procedural style**

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

/* change db to world db */
mysqli_select_db($link, "world");

/* return name of current default database */
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT DATABASE()")) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Default database is %s.\n", $row[0]);
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

**The above examples will output:**

```
Default database is test.
Default database is world.
```